# DevExpress XtraGrid Group By Column behavior on DataSource change

Tags: devexpress, xtragrid

My XtraGrid is assigned a DataTable as its DataSource:

```
        MyXtraGrid.DataSource = MyDataTable;
```

If I drag a column up to the group by panel, and then expand a few of the groupings, and then, with those groups expanded, reassign the XtraGrid's datasource, all but one of the expanded groupings get closed. The grouping that contains the current row remains expanded. Is there a setting that causes all the expanded groups to remain expanded when the DataSource changes?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is, but you can use `BaseView.SaveLayoutToXml` and `BaseView.RestoreLayoutFromXml` as outlined [here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1874).

Comment: `Typically, the RestoreLayoutFrom... methods must be called when a Form/UserControl is being loaded. You can handle the Form.Load/UserControl.Load events to do this.`  Do you have experience calling this routine many times during a user-session? The docs suggest it is something that is called once during form load.

Comment: No issues calling it many times.  We actually allow our users to modify their Grids in real time and then save/load them.  No tricks or  anything to it.